# Symfony Choices Label from Array

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to populate a choice dropdown in Symfony using the array value of a query performed before the ->add of the form builder. I can't for the life of me get the actual label or value despite the fact that the dump($categories) shows the proper values. The dropdown is populated with just 0,1,2. The Category contains a ->getName and a ->getId but I can't reference these.

```
$categories = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.userCreate = :user_id')
        ->andWhere('t.type = :catType')
        ->setParameter('user_id',$userID)
        ->setParameter('catType',$type)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    $builder
        ->add('taskCategory', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $categories,
            'placeholder' => 'Choose a category',
            'choices_as_values' => true,

            ))
```

Comment: Any particular reason for you not to use `entity` form type?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the concept of the 2nd parameter. I thought "choice" was obligatory for a drop down list to be generated as the form object.

Comment: `entity` is part of the DoctrineBridge bundle and adds extra functionality for the `choice` type and lots of magic that cannot be explained in brief comment. Btw, instead of passing your categories through `$options`, since you're using `entity` type, you can include the extra option `query_builder` and pass the callback along with your query - http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I resolved this one. I separated out the query from the label with a function:

```
->add('taskCategory','entity',array(
            'class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\Category',
            'choices'=>$this->fillCategories($options),
            'choice_value'=>'id',
            'choice_label'=>'name',

        ))
```

The "fillCategories" function just returned the data that was required. The key here was to specify the type 'entity' in place of 'choice' in the ->add.

```
$categories = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->where('t.userCreate = :user_id')
        ->andWhere('t.type = :catType')
        ->setParameter('user_id',$userID)
        ->setParameter('catType',$type)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $categories;
```